# How to avoid NumberFormatException in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, numberformatexception

I am trying to concat all the elements of array. So i have written this piece of code. But this is giving NumberFormatException.

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                    sum = sum.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
                    sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(arr[i]));

                }
```

Example: Suppose array elements are 1 5 7 5 6 7 5. Then concatenated number will be 1575675. n is the number of array elements. Here BigInteger is used for very large value of n. Please help me out to avoid this problem.

Comment: 1575675 is not the sum of 1 5 7 5 6 7 5.

Comment: What does you raw data look like?  It would be no surprise that trying to read the string `1 5 7 5 6 7 5` into an integer would cause an exception.

Comment: Yes, having the *EXACT* input would help here.  If that's literally your string then it obviously isn't going to work.

Comment: or is it `1<enter>5<enter>7<enter>...` ?

Comment: please read carefully. I have written I am trying to concat all the elements of array. sum is just a variable.

Comment: you should input the number in multiple lines one number in each line. `Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine())` here if you input in space separated you will get the **NumberFormatException**

Comment: Use a `Scanner` and repeatedly call `nextInt()`

Comment: thanks @Bohemian it works.

Answer (score 0):

This gets really frustrating when trying to help someone.  You aren't showing us your actual input so it's hard to guess what you are really doing.  Please explain how your input is different from that below.  Use the template below to show us what your input really is.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
           throws Exception 
   {
      BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
      //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
      StringReader testVectors = new StringReader( "4\n1\n2\n3\n0\n" );
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( testVectors );
      int n = Integer.parseInt( reader.readLine() );
      int arr[] = new int[ n ];
      for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
         arr[i] = Integer.parseInt( reader.readLine() );
         sum = sum.multiply( BigInteger.TEN );
         sum = sum.add( BigInteger.valueOf( arr[i] ) );
         System.out.println( "sum=" + sum );
      }
   }
```

Output

```
run:
sum=1
sum=12
sum=123
sum=1230
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
> ```

The above line is the problem, As you are stating the input is

```
 1 5 7 5 6 7 5 // Space delimited numbers passed as the command line arguments

reader.readLine(); // This reads the entire line into String
```

So now you have entire input stored into a string with space as the delimiter, but if you try to parse the space-separated String you will get `NumberFormatException.`

To avoid this you can do

```
String [] inputs = reader.readLine().split(" "); // Splitting the input with space
for(String s: inputs) {
 int value =  Integer.parseInt(s); //Now it will parse correctly.
}
```

Comment: And with the input I gave below, his program actually runs.  So again we can't tell what's wrong without the *EXACT INPUT*.

Comment: True, but since his program is failing So the input might not be similar to how you gave.